# Value undefined as a parameter but not out of a function call

Tags: javascript

I am trying out the new JS syntax by using the "new" class system.

I have a store with data. When I call a function from this store it works. When I pass in the store as a parameter within an object, the store is undefined. This looks really weird to me...

I create a Note object and want to store it in my store object.

My code:

```
class NoteController {
    constructor() {
        this.store = new NoteStore(); // Create the store object instance
    }

    CreateNote() { // Create a new note and store it 
    // Other stuff..

        this.store.AddNote(new Note(title, $("#edtNoteText").val()), this.store);

         //this.store.AddNote works fine
        // this.store as a third parameter is undefined!

        // Other stuff..
    }
}
```

In my note object I have this constructor:

```
class Note {
    constructor(noteTitle, noteText, noteStore) {
// Other stuff...

        this.store = noteStore; // noteStore is undefined

        // Other stuff...
    }

// I also tried store without "this" etc.
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: `this.store` won't be `undefined` unless `CreateNote` is called in such a way that `this` does not refer to the `NoteController` instance or unless `// Other stuff` involves callbacks. Please show us more of the implementation of `CreateNote` and how it is called.

Comment: I hope this one here is better: https://pastebin.com/9c0GkTyt

Answer (score 0):

Oh I am really sorry!! I wrote `this.store.AddNote(new Note(title, $("#edtNoteText").val()), this.store);` but it should be `this.store.AddNote(new Note(title, $("#edtNoteText").val(), this.store));` ... I just know C# where I get help from the compiler :S Sorry!